# Unresolved external symbols with git submodules

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++20, git-submodules, c++-modules

I have a solution with 2 projects:

- A static library (Almond)
- A project that uses that static library (Sandbox)

I'm watching and following The Cherno's [Game Engine Series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dZr-53LAlOw&list=PLlrATfBNZ98dC-V-N3m0Go4deliWHPFwT&index=6) except that I'm using C++20 modules. He added [`spdlog`](https://github.com/gabime/spdlog) through `git submodule add`. I did the same thing. Then I added the `$(SolutionDir)Almond\vendor\spdlog\include` to `Additional Include Directories` in the Almond project.

The library builds fine (with a bunch of macro redefinition warnings from `sal.h`). When I try to build Sandbox I don't get any warnings just these errors:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK1120 4 unresolved externals  Sandbox C:\source\Almond\bin\Debug-x64\Sandbox\Sandbox.exe  1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp_MapViewOfFileNuma2 referenced in function MapViewOfFile2   Sandbox C:\source\Almond\Sandbox\Almond.lib(stdout_color_sinks.h_D07BG2BYL2KQ67JA.obj)  1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp_MapViewOfFileNuma2 Sandbox C:\source\Almond\Sandbox\Almond.lib(spdlog.h_UEKL7NPFP4GR8605.obj)  1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "private: static class std::shared_ptr<class spdlog::logger> Almond::Log::s_CoreLogger" (?s_CoreLogger@Log@Almond@@0V?$shared_ptr@Vlogger@spdlog@@@std@@A::<!Log>)   Sandbox C:\source\Almond\Sandbox\Almond.lib(Log.ixx.obj)    1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "private: static class std::shared_ptr<class spdlog::logger> Almond::Log::s_ClientLogger" (?s_ClientLogger@Log@Almond@@0V?$shared_ptr@Vlogger@spdlog@@@std@@A::<!Log>)   Sandbox C:\source\Almond\Sandbox\Almond.lib(Log.ixx.obj)    1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "char const * const spdlog::details::os::default_eol" (?default_eol@os@details@spdlog@@3QEBDEB)  Sandbox C:\source\Almond\Sandbox\Almond.lib(Log.ixx.obj)    1
```

#### Relevant Code

Log.ixx (Almond):

```
export module Log;

import <memory>;

import <spdlog/spdlog.h>;
import <spdlog/sinks/stdout_color_sinks.h>;

export namespace Almond {
    class Log {
    private:
        static std::shared_ptr<spdlog::logger> s_CoreLogger;
        static std::shared_ptr<spdlog::logger> s_ClientLogger;

    public:
        static void Init() {
            spdlog::set_pattern("%^[%T] %n: %v%$");

            // Create multithreaded loggers
            s_CoreLogger = spdlog::stdout_color_mt("ALMOND", spdlog::color_mode::always);
            s_CoreLogger->set_level(spdlog::level::trace);

            s_ClientLogger = spdlog::stdout_color_mt("APP", spdlog::color_mode::always);
            s_ClientLogger->set_level(spdlog::level::trace);
        }

        inline static std::shared_ptr<spdlog::logger>& GetCoreLogger() { return s_CoreLogger; }
        inline static std::shared_ptr<spdlog::logger>& GetClientLogger() { return s_ClientLogger; }
    };
    
}
```

EntryPoint.ixx (Almond):

```
export module EntryPoint;

import Application;
import Log;

#ifdef ALMOND_PLATFORM_WINDOWS

export int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Almond::Log::Init();

    auto app = Almond::CreateApplication();
    app->Run();
    delete app;
}

#endif
```

Main.cpp (Sandbox):

```
import Almond;

class Sandbox : public Almond::Application {
public:
    Sandbox() {}
    ~Sandbox() {}
};

Almond::Application* Almond::CreateApplication() {
    return new Sandbox();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> A project that uses that static library

Is this project compiled as a shared (DLL) or static (.lib) library?
I assume you link your executable with the "A project that uses that static library". If so, you need to enable symbol visibility from that project.

I don't use VS, but CMake can handle that quite elegantly with [GenerateExportHeader](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/GenerateExportHeader.html). You need to include `__decl(dllexport)` and `__decl(dllimport)` to your classes or make all symbol visibility public.

Windows makes all symbols private by default, while UNIX variants make them public by default.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if its exactly the same problem but to solve the linking problem with __imp_MapViewOfFileNuma2  i had to add Onecore.lib and  Onecoreuap.lib to project settings -> linker -> input -> additional dependencies  ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-mapviewoffilenuma2 )

Comment: The "(and no other libraries)" [comment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/apiindex/windows-umbrella-libraries) should not be ignored.